# Comparing two folders contents with automator (quick action)

Tags: automator

I work in a video company. Very often, we copy a heavy load of files from SD cards to our own folders, and before we format the SD cards, we want to check for contents on both directories if they are the same.

I've done some "Quick actions" earlier but this one is too tricky for me. What I want to do is compare the SD directory and the media folder (each one has different structure) and check if both contains the same files, regardless of folders.

Is it possible?

This might sound like it has been asked before, but the solution 've seen is extracting folder contents in another folder, which is not efficient.

Comment: Wouldn’t a DAM - digital asset manager work better here? Seems your workflow to have assets in arbitrary locations is prone to slow down each and every search as you add assets.

Comment: @user3439894 the sd card's name is never the same.  tipically it's a big folder with subfolders containing video files. The media folder's name is never the same neither.

Comment: @bmike It could be a solution, I should take a look and comment with the team, but I'd rather rely on a script rather on an entire software, just for the ease of use. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Have the team check the graphical compare option for images…

Comment: @bmike what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, you should check out everything that software does

Comment: @bmike okay, i'll take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is compare the SD directory and the media folder (each one has different structure) and check if both contains the same files, regardless of folders.

The fact that you want to compare the contents of, I'm assuming, a single *folder* on the **SD card** against another *folder* on the, e.g., **Macintosh HD** containing an entirely different *hierarchical directory structure* ... IMO a *shell script* is the better way to go.

The *example* **shell script** *code*, shown below, get saved as an *executable* and placed within the `PATH` passed to the *shell* in, e.g., **Terminal**, and does the following:

- Creates a list of *filenames* on the **SD Card** containing the *original files* to loop through, attempting to find the *duplicate files* in the *hierarchical directory structure* of the *directory* designated as the *parent directory* containing the *duplicate files* on the e.g. **Macintosh HD**, regardless of where within the *hierarchical directory structure* they may be located.
- If the *original files* do not exist somewhere within the *parent hierarchical directory structure* that supposed to contain the *duplicate files*, then the *original files* that don't already exist get copied to the *parent directory* that's supposed to contain the *duplicate files*.
- If a *filename* exist in both locations, regardless of their *hierarchical directory structure*, a *binary comparison* is preformed, and if there is a difference it's reported.

  - Any differences will need to be addressed manually.
  - Note that because there may be a possibility that a *file* with the same *name* exists more than once in the *parent hierarchical directory structure* that supposed to contain the *duplicate files*, any reported difference in the *binary comparison* will need to be manually verified that the *file* on the **SD Card** also exists elsewhere in the local media folder.

---

In **Terminal**, assumes `pwd` is your **Home** *directory*, run the following *compound command*:

```
f="sdcheck"; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod 0755 "$f"
```

In the opened **sdcheck** document, copy and paste the *example* **shell script** *code*, shown below, into the document. Modify the *value* of `dupdir` *variable* to an existing local *folder* containing the duplicates from the **SD Card**. Then save and close the document.

- <sup>**Note:** I'd move the `sdcheck`  *file* to a location that's within the `PATH` passed to *shell scripts*, then you'd not have to preface the *command* with `./`, or include it's *fully qualified pathname*.</sup>

Back in **Terminal**:

```
% ./sdcheck
Parameter missing!... e.g.: /path/to/directory
Example: sdcheck '/Volumes/SD Card/Media' '/path/to/local_folder'
%
```

Example test:

```
% ./sdcheck '/Volumes/SD Card/Media' /Users/me/Pictures/SD Cards
NOTE: /Volumes/SD Card/Media/IMG_0004.JPG AND /Users/me/Pictures/SD Cards/Card 2/IMG_0004.JPG DIFFER!...
/Volumes/SD Card/Media/IMG_0005.JPG -> /Users/me/Pictures/SD Cards/IMG_0005.JPG
%
```

### *Example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "${1}" ] || [ -z "${2}" ]; then
    echo "Parameter missing!... e.g.: /path/to/directory"
    echo "Example: sdcheck '/Volumes/SD Card/Media' /path/to/local_folder"
    exit 1
fi  

oridir="${1}"
dupdir="${2}"

if [ ! -d  "${oridir}" ]; then
    echo "The directory \"${oridir}\" does not exist!..."
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d  "${dupdir}" ]; then
    echo "The directory \"${dupdir}\" does not exist!..."
    exit 1
fi

while IFS= read -r orifile; do

    while IFS= read -r dupfile; do

        if [ -z "${dupfile}" ]; then
            cp -av "${orifile}" "${dupdir}"
        else
            if ! cmp -s "${orifile}" "${dupfile}"; then
                echo "NOTE: ${orifile} AND ${dupfile} DIFFER!..."
            fi
        fi

    done <<< "$(find "${dupdir}" -type f -name "${orifile##*/}")"

done < <(find "${oridir}" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store')
```

---

### Using the *example* **shell script** *code* in **Automator**

To adapt the *example* **shell script** *code* for use in an **Automator** *workflow*, *application* and or *Service/Quick Action*, it needs to be modified with some additional *code* added, and is done so below.

The *example* **Automator** *workflow* uses **AppleScript** to choose the target *folders*, the **SD Card** and the local *folder* to be compared.

The *example* **shell script** *code* and *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Automator** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

### The **Automator** *workflow* outline:

- **Run AppleScript** *action*
- **Set Value of Variable** *action*

  - **Variable**: `theSDCardMediaFolder`
- **Run AppleScript** *action*

  - **Options** -- **[√] Ignore this action's input**
- **Set Value of Variable** *action*

  - **Variable**: `theLocalMediaFolder`
- **Get Value of Variable** *action*

  - **Variable:** `theSDCardMediaFolder`
  - **Options** -- **[√] Ignore this action's input**
- **Get Value of Variable** *action*

  - **Variable:** `theLocalMediaFolder`
- **Run Shell Script** *action*

---

### The **Automator** *actions*, *code*, and *settings*:

---

In the first **Run AppleScript** *action*, replace the default *code* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
activate

set theMsg to ¬
    "In the next Choose Folder dialog, select the target folder on the SD Card..."

display dialog ¬
    theMsg buttons {"Continue"} default button 1 ¬
    with title "Select the SD Card Media Folder"

set theSDCardMediaFolder to ¬
    the POSIX path of ¬
        (choose folder with prompt ¬
            "Select the SD Card Media Folder:" default location "/Volumes")

set theSDCardMediaFolder to ¬
    characters 1 thru -2 of ¬
    theSDCardMediaFolder as string

return theSDCardMediaFolder
```

---

In the first **Set Value of Variable** *action*, set the *value* the *variable* to: `theSDCardMediaFolder`

---

In the second **Run AppleScript** *action*, replace the default *code* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
activate

set theMsg to ¬
    "In the next Choose Folder dialog, select the Local Media Folder."

display dialog ¬
    theMsg buttons {"Continue"} default button 1 ¬
    with title "Select the Local Media Folder"

set theLocalMediaFolder to ¬
    the POSIX path of ¬
        (choose folder with prompt ¬
            "Select the Local Media folder:" default location "/Users")

set theLocalMediaFolder to ¬
    characters 1 thru -2 of ¬
    theLocalMediaFolder as string

return theLocalMediaFolder
```

- **Options** -- **[√] Ignore this action's input**

---

In the second **Set Value of Variable** *action*, set the *value* the *variable* to: `theLocalMediaFolder`

---

In the first **Get Value of Variable** *action*:

- **Variable:** `theSDCardMediaFolder`
- **Options** -- **[√] Ignore this action's input**

---

In the second **Get Value of Variable** *action*:

- **Variable:** `theLocalMediaFolder`

---

In the **Run Shell Script** *action*:

- **Shell: [/bin/bash]**
- **Pass input: [as arguments]**

Replace the default *code* with the following modified *example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
oridir="${1}"
dupdir="${2}"

logfile="/private/tmp/SD_Card_File_Check_Log.txt"

[ -z "${2}" ] && exit

echo "Begin: $(date -j)" >> "${logfile}"

while IFS= read -r orifile; do

    while IFS= read -r dupfile; do

        if [ -z "${dupfile}" ]; then
            cp -av "${orifile}" "${dupdir}" >> "${logfile}" 2>&1
        else
            if ! cmp -s "${orifile}" "${dupfile}"; then
                echo "NOTE: ${orifile} AND ${dupfile} DIFFER!..." >> "${logfile}"  2>&1
            fi
        fi

    done <<< "$(find "${dupdir}" -type f -name "${orifile##*/}")"

done < <(find "${oridir}" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store')

echo "End: $(date -j)" >> "${logfile}"
echo  >> "${logfile}"

open -e "${logfile}"
```

---

**Notes:**

For the use in **Automator** the *workflow* was saved as an *application*.

When the **Automator** *workflow* finishes, it opens the *logfile* in **TextEdit** for one's review. Here is a sample of what it could look like:

```
Begin: Thu May 27 14:29:59 EDT 2021
NOTE: /Volumes/SD Card/Media/IMG_0004.JPG AND /Users/me/Pictures/SD Cards/Card 2/IMG_0004.JPG DIFFER!...
/Volumes/SD Card/Media/IMG_0005.JPG -> /Users/me/Pictures/SD Cards/IMG_0005.JPG
End: Thu May 27 14:29:59 EDT 2021
```

I did not have an **SD Card** handy to review its *hierarchical directory structure* and as such I use a **DMG** *image* mounted and pathed as shown in the *logfile* output above.

The testing set of *images* was a very small sampling, nonetheless the *code* logic works as expedited as coded.

In the *example* **Automator** *workflow* image below, there is an obvious disconnect in the center between some of the *actions*. This is wanted and due to: **Options** -- **[√] Ignore this action's input**

[image]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **shell script** *code* and *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>

<sub>For **AppleScript** *error handling*... Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: @spund3, Per your comment to my now delete comment to the OP, I have updated shell script for command line use to take two parameters. The rest of the answer involving **Automator** does not need updating and I'd imagine that you'll probably be using it instead of the command line version.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @user3439894's amazing answer above, I was getting the following error:

```
./sdcheck: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./sdcheck: line 34: `done < <(find "${oridir}" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store')'
```

I don't know anything about shell scripting however it seemed to me that the bottom two lines of code in the "*Example* shell script *code*:" code block differed.

```
    done <<< "$(find "${dupdir}" -type f -name "${orifile##*/}")"

done < <(find "${oridir}" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store')
```

I found that if I copied the syntax of the upper line to the lower line that the script appears to run as expected.

```
    done <<< "$(find "${dupdir}" -type f -name "${orifile##*/}")"

done <<< "$(find "${oridir}" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store')"
```

Therefore the full code would become:

### *Example* shell script *code*:

```
if [ -z "${1}" ] || [ -z "${2}" ]; then
    echo "Parameter missing!... e.g.: /path/to/directory"
    echo "Example: sdcheck '/Volumes/SD Card/Media' /path/to/local_folder"
    exit 1
fi  

oridir="${1}"
dupdir="${2}"

if [ ! -d  "${oridir}" ]; then
    echo "The directory \"${oridir}\" does not exist!..."
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d  "${dupdir}" ]; then
    echo "The directory \"${dupdir}\" does not exist!..."
    exit 1
fi

while IFS= read -r orifile; do

    while IFS= read -r dupfile; do

        if [ -z "${dupfile}" ]; then
            cp -av "${orifile}" "${dupdir}"
        else
            if ! cmp -s "${orifile}" "${dupfile}"; then
                echo "NOTE: ${orifile} AND ${dupfile} DIFFER!..."
            fi
        fi

    done <<< "$(find "${dupdir}" -type f -name "${orifile##*/}")"

done <<< "$(find "${oridir}" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store')"
```

P.S. Added as an answer only because I don't have the reputation to add a comment to @user3439894's answer.